# htsql django and manytomany relations

Tags: django, htsql

In HTSQL, can you query for a manytomany relation?

In my Django project (app name is `config`) I have a model `Chapter` with a ManyToMany relation with `FileName`.
When I view the actual sqlite3 database, I see the table `config_chapter_filenames`, (and of course all the django admin stuff is working as expected). But when I open a HTSQL shell session, the table is not listed:

```
htsql-ctl shell -E tweak.django sqlite:/mydb.sqlite  -E tweak.meta
/meta(/table)
```

It lists tables for each of my models, but not the manytomany relations.

I have not been able to figure out a query that will list the filenames for each chapter. I'm guessing that if HTSQL is not seeing my manytomany relations that would explain the problem.

Any ideas?

In the htsql shell I see the models:

```
config_chapter                         
config_chapter_filenames
```

Here is my model:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through='ChapterMembership')
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name = '+')
    filenames = models.ManyToManyField(FileName)
```

My url I'm trying is :

```
http://machinename/htsql/config_chapter{name,filenames}
```

I get this error:

```
bind error: unrecognized attribute 'filenames' in scope of 'config_chapter':
    /config_chapter{name,filenames}
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise I can query and get the name of the chapter and the parent, but still not the filenames.  I made your change to introspect.py, stopped my apache server and restarted. 
Is there something else I'm missing?

One more thing, in the htsql shell:

```
describe config_chapter
Slots for `config_chapter` are:
     id                       integer
     parent_id                integer
     name                     string
     title                    string
     parent                   SINGULAR(config_book)
     config_chapter_filenames PLURAL(config_chapter_filenames)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim,

Thank you for the report, I fixed this bug at:
https://bitbucket.org/prometheus/htsql/changeset/d5dd4e95bcf31f5416b9e17187deebb329e9dd4f

Comment: Thanks Kirill, but I still have trouble. My model looks like this in my 'config' app: Oh I'll add the info to my original question.